# Can I use Laravel Forge with my dedicated server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I have tried to find many way that if I can use [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/)  with my existing dedicated hosting server based on cPanel/WHO or Do I need to purchase a package from Digital Ocean or Amazon Web Service? But Could not get enough information on that.

I need make sure before I purchase Forge.

Answer (score 2):

Forge allows you to instantly create virtual machines using existing cloud providers like digital ocean. Your own virtual machine or dedicated machine therefor is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, therefore this is updated answer. Yes you can install Forge on your own dedicated server. It should also work with previusly installed cpanel/... but some extra configuration will probably be needed.